# 12 Hour Clock Array Sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time, clock

I have been searching on Google and couldn't find any solution to sort an array according to the 12 Hour clock format. I was able to sort the 24 hour clock by converting it to `timestamps` and then using `krsort`. But I am not sure how to sort a 12 Hour Clock ..

Following would be the example of the scenario ..

**Unsorted**

```
array(
    '0' => '03:00 AM',
    '1' => '12:00 AM',
    '2' => '03:00 PM',
    '3' => '01:00 AM',
    '4' => '04:00 PM',
    '5' => '02:00 AM',
    '6' => '12:00 PM',
    '7' => '04:00 AM',
    '8' => '01:00 PM',
    '9' => '02:00 PM'
);
```

**Sorted**

```
array(
    '0' => '12:00 AM',
    '1' => '01:00 AM',
    '2' => '02:00 AM',
    '3' => '03:00 AM',
    '4' => '04:00 AM',
    '5' => '12:00 PM',
    '6' => '01:00 PM',
    '7' => '02:00 PM',
    '8' => '03:00 PM',
    '9' => '04:00 PM'
);
```

The code obviously would work dynamically, so what ever time is given in the array it will be sorted to a 12 Hour Clock in `ascending order` or `descending order`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will accept that format.  So you can use a custom sort ([**usort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)) with a strtotime based callback.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return (strtotime($a) > strtotime($b));
});
```