# Sort a 2d array based on a column containing AM/PM-formatted time ranges

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time, usort

I have a 2D array named **$props**, the structure is as follows,

```
$props = [
    ['name' => 'Mathmatics', 'time' => '03:01:PM - 04:50:PM'],
    ['name' => 'History', 'time' => '11:30:AM - 01:30:PM'],
    ['name' => 'French', 'time' => '01:31:PM - 03:00:PM'],
];
```

I need to sort the array by 'time' key, to get the following result:

```
[
    ['name' => 'History', 'time' => '11:30:AM - 01:30:PM'],
    ['name' => 'French', 'time' => '01:31:PM - 03:00:PM'],
    ['name' => 'Mathmatics', 'time' => '03:01:PM - 04:50:PM'],
];
```

I have found a solution with usort, the solution is as follows:

```
usort($props, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a["time"] - $b["time"];
});
```

However, this is not working maybe because of special format of my time (but I will have to follow this specific time format.) and shows an error and do nothing to the array. The error:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp.....

Comment: `$a["time"] - $b["time"]` tries to subtract a string with another string, which, for obvious reasons, won't work (and doesn't make sense). If you can, add the start time as a separate key in a better format (like `1130`, `1331`, `1501` etc) and use that instead. Something like `return $a['sortTime'] <=> $b['sortTime'];`

Comment: Related: [How to sort an array of times chronologically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6443493/2943403) and [How to sort time by meridiem(AM/PM) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35764737/2943403) and [I need to sort this php array by time. AM PM format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34386137/2943403) and [12 Hour Clock Array Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30905089/2943403) and since your input looks like a db query result: [order by time am and pm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661871/2943403) and [MYSQL order by time am/pm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12952608/2943403)

Comment: "However, this is not working maybe because of special format of my time" - then why not adjust the data within that `usort` closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses `usort` with a special sorting function. Date objects are created using `substr` and `DateTime::createFromFormat`. The spaceship operator is use for comparison.

```
$arr = [
  ['name' => 'Mathmatics', 'time' => '03:01:PM - 04:50:PM'],
  ['name' => 'History', 'time' => '11:30:AM - 01:30:PM'],
  ['name' => 'French', 'time' => '01:31:PM - 03:00:PM'],
];

usort($arr,function($a,$b){
  $dta = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:A',substr($a['time'],0,8));
  $dtb = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:A',substr($b['time'],0,8));
  return $dta <=> $dtb;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Try self: https://3v4l.org/Fq9U5

This variant sorts by the start of the time interval. If only the end is required you can use

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:A - h:i:A',$a['time']); //same with $b
```

Comment: Parsing both time expressions in the range with `h:i:A - h:i:A` results in the datetime object respecting only the end time (which may not be ideal for all use-cases) https://3v4l.org/FAFus

Comment: @mickmackusa : Yes, either it is sorted by start time or by end time. I have no idea how a sort could be done that takes start time and end time into account.

Answer (score 1):

given the format of the date (`03:01:PM - 04:50:PM` etc.) it needs to be made sort able, while keeping the original value.

from your question it could be seen that only the first part (`03:01:PM`) is in use for sorting. even if not the case, lets keep it for the example (it can be easily extended).

given the C locale, transforming the time allows to get a string that can be just sorted (binary string order):

```
          03:01:PM
         /   |    \
    (\d\d):(\d\d):(AM|PM)
       \1     \2     \3
              -->   
             \3\1\2
             PM0301
```

given a single `$time` as input, the transformation can be done with a regular expression search and replace:

```
preg_replace(
    '~^(\d+):(\d+):(AM|PM) - .*$~',
    '\3\1\2',
    $time
);
# ~> "PM0301"
```

Now to actually sort the `$props` array, sort the array of all transformed `$times` and `$props`:

```php
$times = preg_replace(
    '~^(\d\d):(\d\d):(AM|PM) - .*$~',
    '\3\1\2',
    array_column($props, 'time')
);

array_multisort($times, $props);
```

Now `$props` is sorted according to `$times`:

```
[
        [
            'name' => 'History',
            'time' => '11:30:AM - 01:30:PM',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'French',
            'time' => '01:31:PM - 03:00:PM',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Mathematics',
            'time' => '03:01:PM - 04:50:PM',
        ],
];
```

[Example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uOf06).

Comment: [`preg_replace('~(\d\d:\d\d):([AP]).*~', '\2\1', array_column($props, 'time'))`](https://3v4l.org/L9SNp)

Answer (score 1):

For an approach with no regex and fewest iterated function calls, use `array_map()` with iterated calls of `createFromFormat()`, and use that generated sorting array as the first parameter of `array_multisort()` to sort the input array.

[Note that `+` in the `createFromFormat()` method demands that all remaining characters are ignored.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53278639/2943403)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kfCrs))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:A+', $row['time']),
        $props
    ),
    $props
);

var_export($props);
```

Comment: The + in the format is a good solution when the warning in DateTime::getLastErrors() is not a problem.

Comment: @jspit I think you know something that I don't know.  Please explain.

Comment: returns "'warnings' => array ( 8 => 'Trailing data')".
Completely superfluous if I instruct with "+" that the remaining data should be ignored. https://3v4l.org/cf9Wb